# How to make functions of three cylinders?

Tags: geometry, elementary-functions

Three-cylinder with height $4$ $m$ and radii of the base $5,3,1$ $m$ are going to put (in this order). Give an explicit formula for the following functions, you examine the functions on continuity and draw their graphs.

a)The cross-sectional area $F(h)$ of horizontal sections of the body obtained as Function of the height $h\in[0, 12]$.

b) The volume $V(h)$ of the body of height $h\in[0, 12]$.

I don't understand this example, I don't know how to start, if someone can help me I would be really thankful

I understand that the they are on top of each other. But still don't know how to calculate a) and b)

Comment: What about the area between $0$ and $4$, $4$ and $8$, $8$ and $12$?

Comment: When I calculate that what i need to do?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Is it not clear how the surface area of the cross section and the volume underneath is changing if you move the red plane from level zero to level 12?

$$F(h)=
\begin{cases}
\color{blue} {\pi2.5^2},&\text {if } 0\le h<4\\
\color{red}{\text{undefined }},& \text {if }h=4\\
?,&\text {if }4<h<8\\
?,&\text {if }h=8\\
?,&\text {if }8< h\le 12.\\
\end{cases}
$$

And similarly for the volume underneath...

$$V(h)=
\begin{cases}
\color{blue} {\pi2.5^2\times h},&\text {if } 0\le h\le4\\
\color{blue} {\pi2.5^2\times 4+\pi1.5^2\times (h-4)},& \text{ if }4<h\le8\\
?,&\text {if }8< h\le 12.\\
\end{cases}
$$

Graphs:

[image]

Comment: I don't know how to do it for volume

Comment: and how to count that '?'

Comment: Lady, @LadyA, I'll edit forya...

Comment: How to make graph? I don't understand and is h undefined for h=8?

Comment: Lady, for $h=4$ and for $h=8$ the area is undefined, because it depends on the way we place the cylinders on each other... Graph? Ok I plot a graph. Huhh. You ought to do something on your own.

Comment: How to do if I don't understand. Thank you.

Comment: How do I get volume if 8<h≤12?

Comment: I still don't understand what is here funciton, how i can find explizite one?

Comment: Lady, if $h$ is between $8$ and $12$ then $V(h)=\pi\times 2.5^2\times4+\pi\times1.5^2\times4+\pi\times0.5^2\times(h-8)$. There is no more explicite function than the one we have.

Comment: And how to examine the functions on continuity now?

Comment: Lady, $F$ is continuous over $[0,12]$ but at $4$ and $8$. At those latter points $F$ is not even defined because of the undefined nature of tha placing of the cylinders. $V$ is continuous all over the interval. But, now, you tell what kind of school you go to?

Comment: But I get that h for  8<h≤12 is 0,785, so h-8 I'll get negative number hm..

Comment: If $8\le h\le 12$ the $h-8$ is not negative.

Comment: School? What do you think? Guess and I'll tell you if you're right.

Comment: but i get that h there is 0,785

Comment: How can $h$ be $0.785$ if $h$ is between $8$ and $12$?

Comment: But pi*2,5^2 what is that now

Comment: oh area? sorryy